# Prove the following $(R\cap S)^n=R^n \cap S^n$

Tags: relations

I would like to prove the following without induction.
$$(R\cap S)^n=R^n \cap S^n$$
We can start by take $(a,b)\in (R\cap S)^n$ its represent a path from $a$ to $b$ right?

Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: You can use induction and use the fact that intersection is commutative.

Comment: I know how to prove it with induction, I asked without

Comment: My bad. I'm sorry.